# Angular2 spinner for ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a `ngFor` with lots of elements being rendered and I want to show a spinner while the items are not only loaded but also rendered.

I know how I can display the spinner when loading items from the server (i.e. observables), but that only takes a little time in my case. I can see that majority of the time is spent by browser rendering all the `ngFor` elements and I dont know how to make sure that spinner is still displayed for this process. I tried `ngAfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook but thats also triggered before `ngFor` finishes.

So I wonder is there any way to hook into this process? Alternatively can we force Angular2/browser to display `ngFor` items incrementally? I.e. show the items as they are being rendered rather show all of them at once after creating templates.

I am using Angular 2.0.0. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really, really late to the party, here. Just stumbled on this old question when searching for something else.

The problem lies (well, was) probably in the absence of a `trackBy`. This is a parameter often overlooked, but crucial for having good performing `ngFor`s.

The trackBy is used to extract a unique identifier from each item in the enumerable sequence passed to `ngFor`:

```html
<!-- trackById is a method in the component -->
<div *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackById"></div>
```

```js
// the signature of a trackBy method is fixed and as follows
trackById(index: number, item: any): any {
  // you can track by index, by item, by a property. In this sample we track the
  // items via an 'id' property
  return item.id;
}
```

In absence of a `trackBy` function, every single change detection triggered will destroy and recreate the whole list. So, if you have many observable triggering almost simultaneously, the whole `ngFor` will be recreated once for every single observable triggering.
Having trackBy set up, at every change detection the `ngFor` directive will not destroy and recreate everything, but it will only update the items changed, remove what has to be removed and insert the new items.

A nice article describing some use cases:
https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

The API reference documentation:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: The answer is correct, however, you should have provided more information on addressing directly the spinner issue in the question utilising your trackBy.